# Avoid static binding in operations which use hierarchy arguments

Tags: java, design-patterns, dynamic-binding, static-binding

I have found an issue about static binding.

My real class are very extended, so I will use several toy class to express my problem.

We suppose that we have the following hierarchy.

```java
public class Element{}

public class Element1 extends Element{}

public class Element2 extends Element{}
```

I have a `Stock` class which use the different `Element` specialization defined by `Element` hierarchy.

```java
public class Stock{

    public void operation(Element1 e1){
        System.out.println("Operation - " + e1.getClass().getName());
    }

    public void operation(Element2 e2){
        System.out.println("Operation - " + e2.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a `StockManager` which allows to manage a `Stock`.

```
public StockManager{

    Stock stock;
    public StockManager(Stock stock){
        this.stock=stock;
    }

    public void manage(List<Element> elements){
        for(Element element: elements){
            stock.operation(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this code does not compile, because `Stock` does not define a method which includes a `Element` as argument. In this case we could fix the code using different approaches.

First, I will be able to define a method which will define a `Element` as input arg, e.g.

```
public void operation(Element e){
    System.out.println("Operation - " + e.getClass().getName());
}
```

This method could define a switch for managing the different concrete elements (`Element1`, `Element2`). However, this is imposible for me, because the switch violate the [Open/Close Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), and I have a lot (a lot) of concrete elements.

Another alternative, I could use something like the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).
I could send the `Stock` object to a concrete element. And the concrete element will be charge of using the `Stock` operations. So, the class could change to:

```java
public abstract class Element{
    public abstract void stockOperation(Stock stock);
}

public class Element1 extends Element{
    public abstract void stockOperation(Stock stock){
        stock.operation(this);
    }
}

public class Element2 extends Element{
    public abstract void stockOperation(Stock stock){
        stock.operation(this);
    }
}
```

And the `StockManager`.

```
public StockManager{

    Stock stock;
    public StockManager(Stock stock){
        this.stock=stock;
    }

    public void manage(List<Element> elements){
        for(Element element: elements){
            element.stockOperation(stock);
        }
    }
}
```

It allows determine in compile-time the static type of the concrete elements. And the dynamic binding will be charge of call the `stockOperation` method of the correct concrete element (`Element1` or `Element2`). HOWEVER!!, I have duplicate code in the concrete elements, and I will have several concrete elements.

So, I would like know if we know any pattern design or any best practice for solve this issue.
(Another alternative, it maybe to use reflection, but I would not like use it).

Comment: abstract methods can't have code inside them. That is why they are abstract  `public abstract void stockOperation(Stock stock){
        stock.operation(this);
    }` won't even compile

Comment: Of course, this code does not compile, because Stock does not define a method which includes a Element as argument - why do you think this will not compile? You are passing in an Element which is extended by both element1 & 2

Comment: @6ton Because this is overloading, not polymorphism.  When there is overloading, the compiler has to be able to determine, **at compile time**, which overloaded method is being called.  And it can't.

Comment: @ajb You are right, I should have seen that <embarrassed/>

Comment: I don't think there's a really good solution in Java.  (C# may have a way to solve this with method extensions, but I'm not totally familiar with them and it doesn't help you at all anyway.)  There may be a way to solve this by setting up some kind of registry, i.e. a hash table (or equivalent) that maps a `Class<? extends Element>` to an interface that defines the method(s) you want to run for each subclass.  Seems a bit clunky but may be best in terms of avoiding duplication and coupling.  I haven't worked out all the details.

Comment: Of course, this code does not compile. The type are binding in compile-time. And as I told, the `operation(Element e)` was not defined. So, the only class that use the methods are `Element1` and `Element2`.

Comment: You say "I have duplicate code in the concrete elements, and I will have several concrete elements."  It sounds like you need to refactor that duplicate code issue, and then you can use your second approach just fine.

Comment: @tcarvin How would you suggest refactoring this particular example of duplicate code?

Comment: Really in my project, the `StockManager` is a client factory and stock is an Abstract Factory which could generate `Elements1` of different families of elements. The question is that Stock.operation(Element1 e1) or Stock.operation(Element2 e2) return Element1 of Element2 in any technology. Refactor all this hierarchy is very complicate.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you place the individual stock operations in the stock object. No matter if you use a switch or not, as soon as you have another Element type, you'll need to modify stock by adding a new overloaded `operation` to it. And as you said, your Stock class should be closed to modifications.

So you have to do relegate whatever the stock operation is to the Element object itself. This is basically your second suggestion, but you do the implementation in each different Element.

```
public abstract class Element{
    public abstract void stockOperation(Stock stock);
}

public class Element1 extends Element{
    @Override
    public void stockOperation(Stock stock){
        System.out.println("Operation - Element1");
    }
}

public class Element2 extends Element{
    @Override
    public void stockOperation(Stock stock){
        System.out.println("Operation - Element2");
    }
}
```

You will probably need to communicate with the stock object for the real operations. Do that with the stock that was passed to each `stockOperation`, making methods available that allow the elements to get or set whatever is needed inside the stock object, like the result of the operation.

This way, if you have a new Element type, you only need to write the new operation in the new Element, and you can keep the same Stock class without changing it. This is extension rather than modification.

Comment: I don't see the advantage of this.  It potentially puts code that should belong to `Stock` in the wrong class, which I believe leads to increased coupling (and may not work if it needs to refer to member fields defined in `Stock`).

Comment: You have very tight coupling in you have a method per each different Element inside stock anyways. If the code per element is so different that it needs a separate overloaded method in the stock, then it belongs in the element. And you can refer to member fields in Stock using accessors.

Comment: I agree with you @RealSkeptic. It is a good approach, however I hate the duplicate code, but I do not know how remove. I have found a patter design to solve this situation, but I did not find any.

Comment: @kiuby_88 What duplicate code? The code inside each element is code you would have to have written anyway, only you did it inside Stock.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I think I will have the same code in the implementation of the `Element1.operation(Stock stock)` and `Element2.operation(Stock stock)`. I think so, because each element should using the stock an stock operation. What do you think?

Comment: No, you did not understand my solution if you think that. Look at my solution. It is not calling an operation in Stock because if it did that, you'd still need to write all the operations in Stock and add a new method to it each time you have a new kind of element. You write the stock operations **in the Element** and only use things from stock if they are needed for the operation.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, thanks for your reply. It was my first solution. The problem it is that the operation should be part of `Stock` and the elements should should not know the operation working.